# SQL Server: Top Clause Condition Check

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data:

```
 UserId     EffectiveDate               Plan  
    162     2015-07-01 00:00:00.000     LT60
    162     2015-10-16 00:00:00.000     LT60
    162     2016-05-02 00:00:00.000     LT60
    15      2015-07-01 00:00:00.000     LT120
    15      2016-06-01 00:00:00.000     LT50
```

Problem:

Case 1: If plan changes: Pick latest row

Example: For userid 15 Plan changes from LT120,Lt50, So LT50 row will be picked

Case 2: If plan does not change: Pick earliest row

example: For user id 162, plan is same LT60, so first row 2015-07-01 should be picked

I tried using Top 1 function but it fails if plan changes.

Comment: What if the plans change more than once?

Comment: Pick always latest plan..@GordonLinoff

Answer (score 1):

You seem to basically want the first row every time there is a change.  The basic idea is:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(t.plan) over (partition by t.userid) as min_plan,
             max(t.plan) over (partition by t.userid) as max_plan,
             row_number() over (partition by t.userid order by t.effectivedate) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (partition by t.userid order by t.effectivedate desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
     ) t
where (min_plan = max_plan and seqnum_asc = 1) or
      (min_plan <> max_plan and seqnum_desc = 1);
```

Comment: Seems I was a little late with my answer :-) I like your seqnum alias names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using count and row_number as below:

```
Select UserId, EffectiveDate, [Plan] from (
    Select *, RowNum = Row_number() over(partition by userid order by EffectiveDate),
        CntPlan = count([plan]) over(partition by userid, [Plan]),
        CntUser = count([Plan]) over(partition by userid),
        RowNumPlan = Row_number() over(partition by userid order by effectiveDate desc)
        from #Plan
) a
where ( a.CntPlan = a.CntUser and rownum = 1)
    or (a.CntPlan <> a.CntUser and RowNumPlan = 1)
```